# Using FileDialog to browse for a folder in QtQuick

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am trying to figure out how to setup the FileDialog of `QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2` to select a folder instead of file(s) with no success so far. Here is my code. The user should select at least 1 file so that the FileDialog accept button works.

```
FileDialog {
    id:dialogFile;
    title: "Please select folder which contains positive training data";
    folder: shortcuts.home;

    onAccepted: {
        console.log("User has selected " + dialogFile.folder);
    }
}
```

Is there any settings/tricks to make this only browse for folder, something like the FolderBrowserDialog in .NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set your `FileDialog`'s `selectFolder` property to `true`.

See the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html#selectFolder-prop) for further details.